# SBS 2011 Backups showing non-existent drive as unsuccessful

Tags: backup, windows-sbs-2011

I have a client using SBS 2011 and the backup job for the server is showing that the C, D & E drive backups are fine but a fourth drive is unsuccessful. It doesn't list the name in a standard way but instead names it:

\?\Volume{42736666-f0ed-b590-806e6f6e6963}\

[Backup Details Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Soxeh.png)

The only other time I've seen a naming scheme like that for a drive is the drive that Windows SBS backups backup to. It doesn't allow the drive to me accessible through the explorer and gives it a name similar to that.

I checked the backup job settings and it only lists the C (Recovery and OS partitions), D & E drives. Is this some known issue? Is the backup job doing what I think it is and trying to back itself up in addition to the other drives?